# Chrome blocking javascript on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, blocking

I'm working on developing a site on my local machine (Windows 7 Ultimate x64) using WAMP, running APACHE v2.2.22, PHP 5.3.13, and MySQL v5.5.24. I'm developing using Chrome v 22.0.1229.94. I've got quite a bit of javascript in the site, however, and Chrome is relentlessly blocking javascript from running on the page.

Clicking on the little 'blocked javascript on this page' icon in the address bar includes the dropdown that has "Always allow Javascript on Localhost" checked off, and I also have a JavaScript exception in Chrome's settings explicitly saying to always allow JavaScript on 'http://localhost'.

Cookies are being allowed, "Allow all sites to run JavaScript" is checked off, and I have no idea as to why Chrome is not allowing the JavaScript to run.

Overall, it's not imperative to the project that I figure out a fix as both IE9 and Firefox 16.1 are allowing JavaScript and I can utilize them. I am simply curious if there's anything I can do to fix this in Chrome, as I would like to continue developing in Chrome.

Comment: I think one of these could perhaps solve your problem: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Try with http://localtest.me/ [this is a DNS to localhost] that way you can discard that this is a localhost specific problem (also, make sure you are not loading anything form a local path from client side, always request to your server). Have you tried from another machine?

Comment: This sounds strange for me (if JavaScript is allowed for all sites in settings). Are you sure you do not have an extension blocking the stuff? Please provide the URL of the initial web-page and URL of the blocked javascript file.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you notice that JavaScript is only blocked when the console is open (as some are saying), chances are that you disabled JavaScript in the console settings.

1. Open the console.
2. Click the vertical ellipsis icon (or the gear icon on older versions) in the upper right and go to settings.
3. See if the "Disable JavaScript" checkbox is checked.

Comment: This is a great answer. I triple checked my settings of Chrome only to find out through this reply that the javascript console has it's own properties. Many thanks!

Comment: *facepalm* Ka-DERRRRP! Thank God my company doesn't have a time code for "Dev was a complete dumbass."

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, but only when the console is open. When the console is closed, JavaScript loads fine on localhost. Makes it hard to debug things though....

I got around it by opening localhost in an incognito window.

Comment: seems like that was the answer. Every time I loaded the site without the console, the javascript came through fine. An odd little bug. Oh well, I can certainly open the console after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your local server a domain name, may be that would help.

1. Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in notepad
2. Edit that file add a new line at the end
        127.0.0.1  mydomain.com
3. Save, now goto chrome and type in http://mydomain.com/ this should point to your local server.

Since you nolonger run on "localhost" may be chrome will let you pass.

Let's me know if that works. Good luck!