# Meteor Session object not behaving reactively

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working my way through the [Discover Meteor](https://book.discovermeteor.com) tutorial and an annoying problem keeps popping up. When I use the console to change app data, the app doesn't update automagically for reactive data sources as promised. Not sure what is going on. Here's an example to illustrate the problem (and to figure out whether it's the code itself or something else).

**Initialize app and include underscore and iron router:**

```
meteor create testApp
meteor add underscore
meteor add iron:router
```

**Create the following file structure:**

```
.
└── testApp
   ├── .meteor
   |  └── [meteor auto generated files]
   ├── lib
   |  └── router.js
   └── client
      ├── layout.html
      ├── layout.js
      ├── main.html
      └── pageone.html
```

**router.js**

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
});
Router.route('/', {name:'pageone'});
```

**layout.html**

```
<template name="layout">
    <div class="container">
        <header class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{pathFor 'pageone'}}">{{pageTitle}}</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**layout.js**

```
Template.layout.helpers({
  pageTitle: function() { return Session.get('pageTitle') || "placeholder"; }
});
```

**main.html**

```
<head>
    <title>testApp2</title>
</head>
```

**pageone.html**

```
<template name="pageone">
  <div class="message">
    <h1>Test App for SO</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now run the app from the `testApp` directory using the `meteor` command and navigate to `localhost:3000` in the browser.

Now type `Session.set('pageTitle', 'New Title');` into the console.

I am using Chrome and when I do this, the terminal window where I'm monitoring the meteor server prints out `Client modified -- refreshing`. However, nothing happens, even though the `Session` object is supposed to be reactive. Then, if I refresh the tab, I get a blank screen and have to restart the meteor server manually if I want to get my app to work again.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: @Kyll. I've added an MCVE as you suggested. Hopefully that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "problem" with Chrome's console itself. Actually (and I feel dumb now) console has completely separate settings from the browser.

1. Open the console
2. Click on the gear icon.
3. Make sure the "disable javascript" box is not checked.

Now you should be able to modify your app from the console. See [THIS SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020530/chrome-blocking-javascript-on-localhost) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When I search your repository for `Session.get` I can't find any hit, so you are not using any Session variables...
https://github.com/dantzlerwolfe/microscope/search?q=Session.get

Try this to get your example to work and reconsider what you do with `domain`. Thats not how meteor works...

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
    name: function() {
        return Session.get('pageTitle');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added an MCVE as suggested by Kryll above. Even when I add the helper, I am still getting the same problem. Can you recreate the issue based on what I've provided in my edits?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have checked the repository and all works fine. Except changing page title - but it is not supposed to.

Mind, that in `layout.html` you have specified helper `pageTitle` but you have not specified the function. (I assume, that you thought that you can simply access session variables inside a template). In `layout.js` you have to create a new helper called `pageTitle` that returns the session variable. Like so:

```
Template.layout.helpers({
    pageTitle: function(){
        return Session.get("pageTitle");
    }
})
```

Comment: I've added an MCVE as suggested by Kryll above. Even when I add the helper, I am still getting the same problem. Can you recreate the issue based on what I've provided in my edits?