# Why doesn't chrome load my jquery file?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I have been struggling with a problem that drives me crazy.
My Chrome browser won't load my jquery file specified in my script tag.
If i look in developer tools it doesn't even load.
If i try my html file in Safari I can se it load in web inspector and i can see a log in my console. 
For chrome i see no errors. If I view source I can see my html (I am not browsing the wrong file or a cached file).
I've created a small test html file with the same problem.
My simple test code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>testing</title>
    <script src="file:///Users/user/OneDrive/Document/test/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        H1
    </h1>   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('test');
        });
    </script>           
</body>
```

EDIT!
Well this is a bit embarrassing.
Even though you should not code like this it should work. 
But I just learned that disabling javascript in chrome and chrome developer tools are two different things.
I did only check that javascript was enabled in chromes settings.

Time for a break and some coffee..

Comment: By default, chrome doesn't allow to load local resource BUT you should have error in console then. So not sure how do you debug it

Comment: There are many restrictions on accessing resources with a `file://` url. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270999/google-chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-disabled-for-chrome-beta-8) for details.

Comment: @Deltoide You can't reference the jquery file this way. THINK ABOUT IT! You are going to a website which is reading the local files in your computer without your permission.

Comment: @Deltoide You are only allowed to use relative path `/Script/xxxx.js` or absolute path `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure javascript is enabled.
Chrome has separate settings for this in Chrome and in Chromes developer tools, check both.
[More about this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020530/chrome-blocking-javascript-on-localhost/14104224#14104224)